# STATISTIC IN ANYLOGIC

Tags: anylogic

I want to do a statistic about resource utilization! I know that with 'ResourcePool.utilization()' I can do it! But the problem is that the resource work, by a schedule, for 8 hours..but the statistic is over all day! There is a way to investigate the utilization only in their working hours?

Thank u
Miriana

Answer (score 0):

No. You have to record your own statistics manually. This can be done via variables, datasets, etc. But there is no 1 way and it depends on your actual model setup.

Suggest you check lots of the example models that comes with AnyLogic, quite a few are also logging custom statistics. Then try to duplicate that :)